# create-react-app w/ TypeScript & Tailwind CSS; Tailwind's utility classes are not being applied , styling is not working

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I've  been searching all over to try and resolve this issue. I created a React app with TypeScript and installed Tailwind CSS using the React setup shown on the Tailwind site [i prefered site](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app)

Below is my code and configuration. It runs successfully when I do a npm run start, but the Tailwind styles are not applied.

> App.tsx

```
    import { ThemeProvider,createTheme } from '@mui/material';
    import {Routes} from './routes/routes';
    import "./index.css";
    import "./App.css";
    
    const darkTheme = createTheme({
      palette: {
        mode: 'dark',
      },
    });
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
          <Routes/>
        </ThemeProvider>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

> index.tsx

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import { store } from './app/store';
    import App from './App';
    import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
    import "./index.css";
    import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    const container = document.getElementById('root')!;
    const root = createRoot(container);
    
    root.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
      </React.StrictMode>
    );
reportWebVitals();
```

> index.css

```
 @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
    
    tailwind.config.js
    module.exports = {
      purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,html}", "./public/index.html"],
      darkMode: "class", // or 'media' or 'class'
      theme: {
        extend: {},
        fontFamily: {
          sans: ["Roboto"],
        },
      },
      variants: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    };
```

> login-form.component.tsx

```
import { Button, TextField, Link as MuiLink } from "@mui/material";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const LoginForm: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [emailErrored, setEmailErrored] = useState(false);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [passwordErrored, setPasswordErrored] = useState(false);

  const handleSignup = () => {
    if (!email) {
      setEmailErrored(true);
    } else {
      setEmailErrored(false);
    }

    if (!password) {
      setPasswordErrored(true);
    } else {
      setPasswordErrored(false);
    }
  };


  return (
    <div id="center" className="flex justify-center items-center flex-col h-screen gap-8">
      <h1 className="text-6xl">Cryptostatus</h1>
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-2">
        <TextField
          label="Email"
          className="w-80"
          type="email"
          required
          helperText={emailErrored && "Please enter your valid email"}
          value={email}
          onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
          error={emailErrored}
        />
        <TextField
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          className="w-80"
          required
          helperText={passwordErrored && "Password may not be empty."}
          value={password}
          onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
          error={passwordErrored}
        />
        <Link to="/signup" className="justify-self-start self-start mt-2">
          <MuiLink>Sign Up</MuiLink>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <Button variant="contained" id="button1" className="w-80">
        <span className="P-1" onClick={handleSignup}>
          Login
        </span>
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export { LoginForm };
```

the styling is not working  and also in html
i set body dark but it is also not working here is html

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="dark">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    />

<!-- Google icon-> (Material) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@40,400,1,0" />

   
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  
    <title>React Redux App</title>
  
  <body class="dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200">

  <div id="root"></div>
</body>  
</html>
```

how to solve this ?